# Prevent UIActionSheet from dismissing on ipad

Tags: ios, ipad, uiactionsheet

I have a universal app that uses a UIActionSheet.  The selection is mandatory, which works fine on the iphone, but on iPad it is presented as a popover, so tapping outside of it dismisses it, which I don't want to allow.

I know that there is a delegate method for UIPopoverController I could use, but I don't think I can get access to the UIActionSheet's popover controller to set the delegate etc...

Anyone know how I can do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't do what you want with `UIActionSheet` on the iPad. Use `UIAlertView` or some custom widget to get the desired behavior.

Comment: That really stinks!  I was afraid of that...

Answer (score 0):

It's possible using undocumented APIs, see
See [Accessing UIPopoverController for UIActionSheet on iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806988/accessing-uipopovercontroller-for-uiactionsheet-on-ipad) about changing `passthroughViews` for `UIPopoverView` which is an undocumented ancestor of `UIActionSheet`.

Another solution would be to override `[UIApplication sendEvent:]` and filter the touches coming outside the action sheet.

I recommend you to use a different widget for modal selection. Users don't expect `UIActionSheet` to be modal, so it would be only confusing to them.